# value over written in the array during loop

Tags: c

I am currently trying to convert an equation into simpler form and found out that my codes are over writing the value at the end of the loop.

I have found out similar discussions but not exactly what I am looking for. Most of articles were using other languages so I couldn't get the answer.

Any answers are appreciated and thanks in advance.

followings are my code

```
int index = 0;
int result = 0;
char tresult[100];
char *equation[100] = { NULL, };
char *temp = strtok(input, " ");

for(int i = 1; i < x; i = i + 2)
{
    char *temp_sign = equation[i];
    
    if(*temp_sign == '*')
    {
        result = atoi(equation[i - 1]) * atoi(equation[i +1]);
        sprintf(tresult, "%d", result);
        equation[i - 1] = tresult;
        sprintf(equation[i], "%d", 0);
        sprintf(equation[i + 1], "%d", 0);
    }
}

for(int j = 0; j < x; j++)
{
    printf("%s ", equation[j]);
}
```

Expected input

```
5 * 3 + 1 * 2
```

targeted output

```
15 0 0 + 2 0 0
```

I will remove 0 by adding extra codes to make it as

```
15 + 2
```

but currently, my output looks like

```
2 0 0 + 2 0 0
```

When I print out the value in the loop, all the values were correctly shown. What may be the cause of such problem?

Comment: Without a proper [mre] all we can do is *guess*. And my guess is that  `equation` is an array of pointer, and that all elements of it will point to the single array `tresult`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry for the confusion. I just edited my code which includes the variable types. As what your have guessed, equation is in the format of pointer array. could that be the issue?

Comment: Is this code complete? Do you ever initialize `equation` with anything other then `NULL` before running the loop? Right now, it looks like a lot of undefined behavior, and it is a miracle your program isn't crashing.

Comment: Yes that's the issue, when you do the assignment `equation[i - 1] = tresult;` you make `equation[i - 1]` point to (the first character of) `tresult`. It doesn't copy the contents of `tresult`. That means you will have at least two pointers to the very same `tresult`.

Comment: [mre] for your code https://onlinegdb.com/V_Gq3AKmZ

Comment: @LevM. equation will be updated as user inputs the equation into it. I have used strtok to slice within blanks and input them into the equation.

Comment: Where is the code that actually initialize `equation`? You do not do what you described in the code you published!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to understand if we draw out the pointer instead.

Assuming that `input` is initially equal to `"5 * 3 + 1 * 2"`, then after the loop `equation` will look something like this:

```
+-------------+
| equation[0] | ------------------------\
+-------------+                         |
| equation[1] | --> | input[2] | ... |  |     +------------+-----+
+-------------+                          >--> | tresult[0] | ... |
| equation[2] | --> | input[4] | ... |  |     +------------+-----+
+-------------+                         |
| equation[3] | ------------------------/
+-------------+
| equation[4] | --> | input[10] | ... |
+-------------+
| equation[5] | --> | input[12] | ... |
+-------------+
```

As seen in the above "drawing" both `equation[0]` and `equation[3]` will be pointing to the first character of the single array `tresult`.

And `tresult` will always contain the contents last written into it with `sprintf(tresult, "%d", result)`. Which in your example will be `"2"`.